# Adding a character in a sentence

Tags: javascript

I want to add an space in a sentence when ever these is a character of 'e',the sentence is:"weservethepeopleindeed" and the sentence will be dynamically generated

Comment: Okay, and your question is...?  Have you tried anything at all?  Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.  We will help you, but we won't do it for you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Try to do the work. **If** you run into a *specific* problem doing so, show what you've tried, what research you've done, etc., and people will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could help you solve your problem !

```
string.replace(/e/g,'e ');
```

Check the below code -

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace(/e/g, "e ");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">weservethepeopleindeed</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

If you need a proper sentence to be formed then  i guess you need to write custom method based on what and where the data is coming from.

Comment: Thank you DHARSHAN BHANDARI,I was till now trying to add the character and then from that string I was trying to add the space this was where I struck

Comment: Yea no problem  !! Dont forget to vote and  mark that as an answer ☺

Answer (score 1):

You can do a javascript string replace.
For your variable str.

```
str = str.replace(/e/g,"e ")
```